# Deleting/Destroying/Removing a QGraphicsItem from a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt

I feel like this question has been answered somewhere before, but I cannot find the answer for the life of me (particularly because of the synonyms in the title spreading the solutions around). I want a definitive answer to which is the best way to delete a QGraphicsItem from a scene. Let's take the simplest scenario: A simple "rubberband" rectangle.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Rubbery(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.origin = event.scenePos()
    self.rect = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(self.origin.x(), self.origin.y(), 0, 0, None, self)

  def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.rect.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.origin, event.scenePos()).normalized())

  def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.rect.setParentItem(None)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

scene = Rubbery()
scene.setSceneRect(0,0,500,500)
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()

app.exec()
```

If you look at the `mouseReleaseEvent`, that's where I'm having my issues. I want to completely and utterly remove it from the scene and update it immediately, but calling `self.update()` does nothing. I want this change to be reflected immediately. In PySide it seems `del` took care of things well, but here's it's unclear.

**Options:**
`del`
`setParent(None)`
`setParentItem(None)`
`hide() + deleteLater()`

Answer (score 2):

`QGraphicsScene` has a `removeItem()` method:

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.removeItem(self.rect)
```

The rectangle will be removed immediately when the mouse is released.